# Editing a PDF in iBooks OK?

Tags: pdf, books

I have a PDF in which every page has an image that is crooked by almost ninety degrees.  Not all the same amount of rotation and some are clockwise, while some are widdershins.  I don't want to wait to put it on my iPad till after the nasty task of fixing this.

I know how to find and edit the PDF in the iBooks library.  Is there any downside to doing so?

It would be a bit of proctalgia to delete from iBooks and re-import after every edit.  I have to re-sync either way, but I do that often anyway.

Comment: [Proctalgia](https://patient.info/doctor/proctalgia-fugax-and-anal-pain) definition. Quite erudite, @WGroleau.

Comment: Well, I did work in health care for ten years.

Comment: Did you mean to say "Quite a Luddite" and get autocorrected? :-)

Comment: Nope. I'm a writer and a sesquipedalian and cherish words I've not run across before!

Comment: While I have no complaint with the definition you cited, I prefer the one of four syllables.

Comment: I've already used proctalgia twice in conversation. No worries. I cited the definition for those who need to know!

Comment: Proctalgia is medical term for ass pain. Do not click @IconDaemon’s link, horrible ads will crash your browser.

Comment: @MattM. - perhaps you should consider using an ad blocker in your browsers. [This definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/proctalgia) may have fewer ads. I use NeverAds for Safari under iOS 11.latest.